# Projection of a line from a point

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question I can't solve. I have to find a projection of a line defined by the equation:

$$\frac{(x-1)}{2}=\frac{y}{3}=\frac{(z+1)}{4}$$

from a point $A(6,5,4)$ on to a plane with an equation $x+2y+2z-15=0$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to think about this problem? What does the answer mean, conceptually?

Comment: I have found the breakthrough point of this line though the plane it has coordinates M(3,3,3) I was thinking about finding the breakthrough point of line that passes through A but the solution I get doesn't match the one from the textbook.

Comment: @Aida: A line has infinitely many "symmetric" forms (of the type given in your question) and infinitely many parametric representations, because each form relies on a point and a direction vector, and there are infinitely many of each on a specific line. Thus, it's entirely possible your answer is correct even if your book's answer differs.

Answer (score 1):

the points on the line is of the form $$(1+2t, 3t, -1+4t). $$ this line intersects the plane for $t$ given by $$1(1+2t)+2(3t) +2(-1+4t) = 15 \to t = 1$$ therefore the point is $(3,3,3).$

we can now project the vector $(2,3,4)$ which is parallel to the line onto the plane perpendicular to $(1,2,2).$  let us write $$(2,3,4) = k(1,2,2) + \epsilon, \epsilon \perp (1,2,2) \tag 1  $$ taking the dot product of $(1)$  with $(1,2,2)$ gives $2 + 6+8 = k(1+4+4)\to k = 16/9.$  you can now compute $\epsilon$ from $(1).$  once you have $\epsilon,$ that is the projection on the plane, the projected line is $$(3,3,3) + k\, \epsilon, k \text{ any real number} $$